# React native, redux, redux ORM, expo ... trying to make it all work. __fbbatchedbridge

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, expo, redux-orm

In the spirit of 4th July, I want to establish something thus I am not giving up on this. I've been trying to make it work for a while now(not just today) and frankly I am sick of react native and it's habit of breaking every time I pull a package from npm.

#### package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.24.1",
    "expo": "^18.0.4",
    "react": "16.0.0-alpha.12",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-18.0.1.tar.gz",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.5",
    "redux": "^3.7.1",
    "redux-orm": "^0.9.4",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-react-native": "^2.0.0",
    "redux-orm-proptypes": "^0.1.0"
  }
```

#### App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';  
import store from './store';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Text>asdasdasD</Text>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

#### store/index.js

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunkMiddleware from 'redux-thunk';
import rootReducer from '../reducers/';

const configureStore = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  applyMiddleware(thunkMiddleware)
);

export default configureStore;
```

#### reducers/index.js

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { createReducer } from 'redux-orm';
import orm from '../models';

const rootReducerCombined = combineReducers({ orm: createReducer(orm) });

export default rootReducerCombined;
```

#### models/index.js

```
import { ORM } from 'redux-orm';
import Job from './JobModel';  

const orm = new ORM();
orm.register(Job);

export default orm;
```

The rest of the stuff is pretty basic. Project is blank expo project that I wanted to create for the sake of [using ORM in redux](https://github.com/tommikaikkonen/redux-orm).

[image: redux orm error]

On a side note, and I much prefer a solution to my question than having the focus on this, I can not help but think what am I missing? Yes I am very new to react and react native but why does everyone love react native? I agreed to use it on a project even though I did not want to and now I spend most my of time looking through github issues to make everything in my package json work. Everytime I go "hey this looks good I want to use it" and run the npm install, everything breaks ... So, honestly, what is the point of working to work? Am I looking at this all wrong?

Comment: Can you post a link to the project on Github? I'll take a look. This certainly sounds frustrating!

Comment: Wow I'd really appreciate that. [I've made a repo](https://github.com/ODelibalta/reduxormexposf). Perhaps we once it is up and running, it can stay public for everyone else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried out your repository and managed to get it running. The first thing I did was just run `exp start --ios` to see if that would work. It showed me the following error:

[image: error on first run]

So I went to App.js and saw that on line 9, Text was used but it wasn't imported, so I imported it from react-native and the app rendered with some text.

Next, I looked at the logs and saw this warning:

```
  [exp] jest-haste-map: @providesModule naming collision:
  [exp]   Duplicate module name: babel-preset-react-native
  [exp]   Paths: /Users/brent/coding/reduxormexposf/node_modules/react-native/babel-preset/package.json collides with /Users/brent/coding/reduxormexposf/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/babel-preset-react-native/package.json
  [exp]
  [exp] This warning is caused by a @providesModule declaration with the same name across two different files.
```

I then checked the package.json and saw that there were a bunch of babel modules, but the babelrc didn't actually use any of those -- it only used `babel-preset-expo`. So I removed all of those plugins, closed the packager, and ran `exp start --ios` again and the warning went away.

I'm not sure how you ended up in the state where you had an error about `__fbBatchedBridge is undefined` as in your post, there are a number of ways that can happen. The error message is not very descriptive at all and it should be improved. It's quite possible that the packager was not running (`exp start`). Let me know if the problem persists, but the other issues should be resolved. I submitted a pull request with the changes I discussed: https://github.com/ODelibalta/reduxormexposf/pull/1

Comment: You are a hero. Finally I am happy about using this stack because I think orm way is going to be soo clean. Thank you soooo much

Comment: not a problem, I'm glad we were able to resolve it! feel free to ping me further on slack.expo.io or forums.expo.io for anything that isn't a good fit for StackOverflow